# Add elements to non-wrapping container, overflowing on left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to add elements to a container using JS. When the total width of the inner elements is bigger than the width of the wrapping `DIV`, the leftmost element should disappear to the left side.

I thought I'd be able to get the desired effect by using

```
p {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

but it doesn't work, because elements are floating to the next line.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RqU3E/2/

Thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgzqs/)?

You need to wrap the container with an element that has a fixed width/height and overflow:hidden:

```
width: 200px;
height: 23px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

As soon as the width of the container is bigger than the width of the wrapper, align the container to the right side of this wrapper (via JS):

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/RqU3E/3/).

changes to CSS:

```
.container{display:table;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: to me, this doesn't work - the container DIV gets higher and the inner elements wrap...